# Is there a way to put a 'screen' over widgets?

Tags: android

I have several widgets, `TextView`, `Button`, `SeekBar`, `EditText` and `RadioButton`. I want to be able to click these widgets and have a `DialogBox` open instead of interacting with the actual widget. My thought was to put the widgets in their own `LinearLayout` and put a `ClickListener` on the `LinearLayout` but that only seems to work for `TextView`. Is there a way to put the `LinearLayout` in front of the widget so that it get's the clicks instead of the widget? Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your can create an Activity and set it to the Dialog Theme

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Then all you have todo is fire your intent and it will bring up a Dialog box that is on top of your Z layer.
Plus you can startActivityForResult() if you need information back from the DialogActivity.